Does CICω prove Con(ZF)?
Given that most major proof assistants are based on type theory (Coq, Lean, Agda), while the orthodox dogma is that all mathematics is based on set theory, it is very natural to ask how set theory and type theory compare in terms of logical strength.
One can devise several related but distinct notions of strength, among which: arithmetic strength (which arithmetic statements are provable), consistency strength (implications between the consistencies of systems, proven over weak systems), which functions $ℕ → ℕ$ are definable, or the proof-theoretic ordinal from ordinal analysis. I will focus on consistency strength in this question, but answers involving other types of strength are welcome.
Since there are many type theories out there, sometimes with very subtle differences, let me clarify which one exactly I am referring to: by CICω I mean the calculus of inductive constructions with ω universes, i.e., the pure type system with an impredicative sort at the bottom of a predicative tower of ω sorts, with the addition of local definitions (let) admitting δ-conversion (e.g., let T := U in fun (x : T) -> f x is well-typed if f : U -> V), and with inductive types as described by Paulin and Coquand. To ask a fully well-defined question just in case these things matter: cumulative universes, no η-expansions, no native fix/match and guardedness condition (only recursors), Russell- (not Tarski-) style universes, no mutually inductive types, no funky things like inductive-recursive types, no definitional proof irrelevance à la Lean. Most importantly: no extra axioms at all. This is more or less the theory of Coq or Lean, with a few differences from each.
Question: Does CICω prove the consistency of ZF set theory?
Some background:
This excellent answer by Loïc Pujet on this site compares many type theories in strength — though with definable functions, not consistency strength like here. It is noted that CCω lies between Z and ZF. But this doesn't say what power inductive types add to CICω compared to CCω. It is also noted that if we add LEM + a variant of choice to CICω, we get something comparable to ZFC with inaccessibles. This is proven in the paper Sets in Types, Types in Sets by Benjamin Werner. But here, I am asking about the pure CICω without axioms.
Theorem 20 in Werner's paper is that ZFC with $n$ inaccessible cardinals can be encoded in CIC with $n+2$ universes plus LEM plus the axiom TTDA at level $n+2$, where TTDA (“Type-Theoretic Description Axiom”) at level $i$ is defined as:
$$Π (A B : \textsf{Type}_i), Π (P : A → B → \textsf{Prop}),
\\ (Π a : A, ∃ b : B, P a b) → (∃ f : A → B, Π (a : A), P a (f a))$$
This is a form of choice in type theory. Given this, one might expect that “by removing choice on both sides”, we would get equiconsistency between ZF with some inaccessibles and CICω. Unfortunately, I am stuck proving that this is the case: I do not even see how to interpret pure ZF (no inaccessibles) in CICω. The basic problem is that Werner uses TTDA not only to interpret the axiom of choice, but also to interpret the axiom of replacement, and it is not clear how to do without TTDA for replacement.
First, to get rid of the need to interpret LEM, instead of interpreting ZF in CICω, we can try to interpret IZF instead. IZF (Intuitionistic ZF, not to be confused with Constructive ZF) is an intuitionistic variant of ZF which was proven equiconsistent with ZF by Friedman [1]. IZF is basically ZF over an intuitionistic base logic, with two additional modifications:

The usual formulation of the axiom of regularity/foundation as “every non-empty set has an ∈-minimal element” is inherently classical (it entails LEM easily), so we replace it by ∈-induction. (If you ask me, this is the best way to define well-founded relations even classically anyway.)

The axiom (schema) of replacement (for each formula $φ(x, y)$)
$$∀ X, ((∀ x ∈ X, ∃! y, φ(x, y)) ⇒ ∃ Y, ∀ x ∈ X, ∃ y ∈ Y, φ(x, y))$$
is replaced by the axiom (schema) of collection
$$∀ X, ((∀ x ∈ X, ∃ y, φ(x, y)) ⇒ ∃ Y, ∀ x ∈ X, ∃ y ∈ Y, φ(x, y))$$
which is the same with the hypothesis weakened to $∃$ instead of $∃!$.


To build a type of sets, we can use the same technique as Werner, first proposed by Aczel in the context of MLTT with W-types, which is to use the inductive type written like this in Coq syntax:
Inductive V : Type :=
| make_set : forall (X : Type) (f : X -> V) -> V.

The intuition is that make_set X f is the set “$\{f(x), x : X\}$”. (We can use an empty type for $X$ to get the empty set and bootstrap from there.)
Using suitable interpretations of equality and membership (see the paper), one can interpret all axioms other than collection without too many difficulties.
For collection, I am stuck. What I am able to prove is the following which looks like replacement:
forall (A : V)
       (φ : V -> V)
       (φ_respectful : forall a b, a == b -> φ a == φ b) :
  exists B, forall y, y ∈ B <-> exists x, x ∈ A /\ φ x == y.

(where (==) : V -> V -> Prop is the interpretation of equality and (∈) : V -> V -> Prop is that of membership). This is essentially trivial: if A is make_set X f, we just need to compose f by φ.
Intuitively, I thought this would be “morally” equivalent to replacement. The way I view it, the standard formulation of replacement uses a formula $φ(x, y)$ and an assumption $∀ x ∈ X, ∃ y, φ(x, y)$ as a sort of crutch for the fact that the universe $V$ is a proper class and we don't have class functions in standard set theory, but the “take away” of replacement is that “the image of a set by a class function is a set”, and this is what the above says.
Unfortunately, this is not so clear. Under the natural interpretation of IZF propositions into types, the proposition $∀ x ∈ X, ∃! y, φ(x, y)$ is forall x : V, x ∈ X -> exists! y : V, φ x y, and I do not see how to get a function V -> V from this without at least some variant of the axiom of choice — and that is what Werner did. A fortiori, we seem to need a form of choice to prove collection (we could do with just unique choice for replacement, but now we seem to need the full choice).
One obvious way one might imagine to fix this would be to replace that exists ($∃$, in Prop) with an { ... & ...} ($Σ$, in Type). Unfortunately, this breaks the proof of the schema of specification and (I think) powerset, which is unsurprising because these are inherently impredicative (cf. the differences between IZF and CZF).
Another naïve way could be to interpret the universe by
Inductive V : Type :=
| make_set : forall (X : Type) (R : X -> V -> Prop), (forall x, exists! y, R x y) -> V.

so that we could build a set from just a functional relation without needing to reify it to a function. This ⓐ would only work for replacement, not collection, and ⓑ fails immediately because the inductive type is not well-formed, as the recursive occurrence of V is negative.
The question, therefore, is whether we can find another interpretation of IZF's universe to make collection provable, or whether the collection schema actually hides some weak form of choice that makes it impossible to model in CICω.
Related questions and papers:
Bruno Barras' habilitation thesis is similar to Werner's work for the part interesting here, i.e., uses TTDA. It states:

It is sometimes conjectured that ZF is stronger than the Calculus of Inductive Con- structions with its predicative universe hierarchy. This would mean that a model of ZF can be constructed in Coq only resorting to axioms.

(I believe “predicative” is a slip for “impredicative”.) This says the question I'm asking is open. That was in 2012, so, with the pace at which the field of type theory is developing, I imagine there might have been new developments I haven't found.
I found this related MathOverflow question, with many answers but no definitive answer to this precise question that I can see. There are results about CC (no inductive types), there are references to Werner's work, and a lot of “it's a complicated topic that needs more research”.
There's also this other related MathOverflow question which asks about the converse direction, interpreting type theory in set theory.
[1] Harvey Friedman. The consistency of classical set theory relative to a set theory with intuitionistic logic. The Journal of Symbolic Logic, 38(2):315–319, 1973

I once tried to work on this problem with no success. I think your question is open, and the currently the best lower bound for CIC should follow from Rathjen's result in "Constructive Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, power set, and the calculus of constructions," which is beyond Zermelo set theory but far weaker than ZF. You should also check Gambino's Laurea thesis (you may get it by contacting Gambino.)

@HanulJeon should this be an answer?

I'll try, but I don't think I can post a full answer within a week or two.

NB It doesn't need to be as long as the question ;-)
